# c# linq: how to submit object to database as a new record

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, insert

I have the following object:

```
namespace LearnLINQ1
{
    [Table(Name="testMe")]
    public class SubmitTest
    {
        [Column(Name="FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        linqLayerDataContext db;
    }
}
```

And i've used the same thing with a constructor:

```
namespace LearnLINQ1
{
    [Table(Name="testMe")]
    public class SubmitTest
    {
        [Column(Name="FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        linqLayerDataContext db;

        //constructor
        public SubmitTest(string first, string last, int phone, linqLayerDataContext db)
        {
            this.FirstName = first;
            this.LastName = last;
            this.PhoneNumber = phone;
            this.db = db;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm using the following code to instantiate the object and attempt to add it to the database as a new record:

```
SubmitTest test = new SubmitTest { FirstName = "Jeremy", LastName = "Stafford", PhoneNumber = 23 };
db.testMes.InsertOnSubmit(test);
```

But im getting the error:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertOnSubmit(LearnLINQ1.testMe)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\LearnLINQ1\LearnLINQ1\Form1.cs  42  13  LearnLINQ1
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert
>   from 'LearnLINQ1.SubmitTest' to
>   'LearnLINQ1.testMe'   C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\LearnLINQ1\LearnLINQ1\Form1.cs  42  39  LearnLINQ1

I'm not sure if there was something im missing in the class definition... kinda new to the concept. Can someone point me in the right direction?

================================
UPDATE: Ok so i made some changes

the customer class:

```
namespace LearnLINQ1
{

    public class Customer
    {
        [Table(Name = "testMe")]
        public class SubmitTest
        {
            [Column(Name = "FirstName")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Column(Name = "LastName")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [Column(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
            public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

And the test code:

```
namespace LearnLINQ1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            linqTestDataContext db = new linqTestDataContext();

            Table<Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();
            var cus = new Customer { FirstName = "Jeremy", Lastname = "Stafford", Age = 31 };
            db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cus);

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is with the customer class. it is giving the following error:

> Error 1   Missing partial modifier on
>   declaration of type
>   'LearnLINQ1.Customer'; another partial
>   declaration of this type
>   exists    C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\LearnLINQ1\LearnLINQ1\Customer.cs   11  18  LearnLINQ1

Comment: There should be another collection in the data context - something called something like `SubmitTests`. Basically, you're trying to store a `SubmitTest` object into a collection of `TestMe` objects - that just doesn't work...

Comment: You could as well use the constructor you provided: SubmitTest test = new SubmitTest ("Jeremy", "Stafford", 23, db);

Comment: nm, tore it down and restarted. there were some conflicts created by the fact that i didn't realize that these objects were inferred by the data context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LearnLINQ1.testMe is the object you need to create not LearnLINQ1.SubmitTest

Comment: how do i instantiate an object testMe from a class called testMe that does not exist?